# Bind Listbox Item in Middle which Highest Text(eg.numbers) in wp8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, listbox

I need to Display Dynamic Data which Contains Text block(text are 90,20,30,50,70).in this case I need display like which is greatest value should be in Middle in List box and second highest should be right side and third highest should be left side ,In Horizontally.

View:
20 50 90 70 30

```
 <ListBox  Name="wifiListboxItems" Height="350" Width="467" Canvas.Left="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="wifiListboxItems_SelectionChanged_1" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                                <wptoolkit:WrapPanel  Margin="150,0,150,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                </wptoolkit:WrapPanel>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Name="stackpanle" Loaded="stackpanle_Loaded"  Orientation="Horizontal" Height="auto" Width="auto">
                                    <Grid Name="gridim">
                                        <Border Height="{Binding Name,Converter={StaticResource HeightConverterTest}}" Width="130" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#96345a" CornerRadius="0,0,80,80"/>
                                        <Image  Name="imgicon"  Height="50" Width="50" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,40,0,50" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Source="{Binding AppIcon}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Name="tblPer" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ></TextBlock>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
public class HomePageHeightConverterr:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string temp = value.ToString();
        temp = temp.Remove(temp.Length - 1, 1);
        double standardHeight = 120;
        double height;
        double.TryParse(temp, out height);
        double returnHeight = standardHeight + (height * 2);
        return returnHeight;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

here I will get returnHeight like 90,40,60,70,80.Now I have to bind in Listbox which is highest in center ,second highest is in right side and third highest is left side.

Any help could be appreciate?

Comment: where is the use of listbox here..? post some code you've tried till now.. It seems your question is easy but you need to elaborate more.

Comment: sort your data as you want in the viewmodel and then bind to listbox. Share some code to show your efforts if you really want community to help you

Comment: @KevalLangalia and nit ,Please check it out I edited some code.